# I am being given a syntax error with no obvious reason in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

```
<script>
function changeLight(){
    lightOne
    lightTwo
    lightThree
}
function lightOne(){

}
var list1=[
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit red.png"
    ]
var list2=[
    "../../../Pictures/lights/orange.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit orange.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/orange.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit orange.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit orange.png"
]
var list3=[
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit green.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png"
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png"
]
</script>
```

This is a screenshot of the error message and code in dreamweaver

[image: .]

I dont see any reason for there to be an error on this line since it is not finding an error on the line above.

I am a begginer in javascript so this code is messy.

Comment: You forgot the commas (`,`) between the elements of your arrays.

Comment: You're also not calling the function from `changeLight`. And two of the "functions" you try to call(?) doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg function call is on a button, but yeah seems to call a function that does nothing and two functions that don't exist

Comment: @Joachim I am still working on that part of the code, the functions will be using the arrays so i do not want to try and use them if they are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be:

```
<script>
function changeLight(){
    lightOne();
    // lightTwo();
    // lightThree();
}
function lightOne(){

}
var list1=[
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/red.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit red.png"
    ];
var list2=[
    "../../../Pictures/lights/orange.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit orange.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/orange.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit orange.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit orange.png"
];
var list3=[
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/lit green.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png",
    "../../../Pictures/lights/green.png"
];
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be something painfully obvious to anyone that knows JS.